# how to get view id using outcome in navigation case in faces-config.xml in jsf

Tags: jsf, faces-config

I'am trying to retrieve to-view-id using from-outcome in the navigation-case in  faces-config.xml, I'm using JSF 1.2. Please let me know if there is a in- built method or how to write the code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but you can get the ViewID through your server side code in JSF using:

```
String viewId = getFacesContext().getViewRoot().getViewId();
```